# How to pass an optional parameter to every child when rendering component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is an non-optional prop for the parent. I want to pass the property `foo` to every child here without explicitly requiring every child component to define the property.

```js
interface Props {
    foo: true;
}

export class Parent extends React.Component<Props>{
    public render(){ 
        // pass `foo` to every child that accepts the parameter here... somehow...
        return (<p>{this.props.children}</p>)
    }
}
```

Super Parent class which acts as a wrapper for both the parent and child

```js
export class SuperParent extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Parent>
                <Child/>
                <ChildTwo/>
            </Parent>
        );
    }
}
```

This child accepts the property `foo`:

```js
interface ChildProps{
    foo: boolean;
}

export class Child extends React.Component<ChildProps>{
    render(){
        const {foo} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                {foo && <p>Hello World!</p>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This child does not accept the property `foo`:

```js
export class ChildTwo extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return ("NO FOO HERE");
    }
}
```

**Reasoning:**
I'm creating a component that will have a state. It will pass that state to it's children, making them render differently. However, this component operates on a root directory level, and adding the property to every child would require me to alter a lot of components, including native code. I want to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use React.cloneElement to pass a new prop to the children.

```
        {this.props.children &&
          React.Children.map(this.props.children, x =>
            React.cloneElement(
              x as React.ReactElement,
              { foo: this.props.foo },
              null
            )
          )}
```

Also need to make a few changes, namely change the Parent interface and make foo optional in the Child interface.

Note that in this example the foo prop will be passed to every children, if you don't want to pass the prop to some children you would have to use some kind of filter on the `React.Children.map` function, maybe using `displayName`

Full example : https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-bird-woew7

```
interface Props {
  foo: boolean;
}

export class Parent extends React.Component<Props> {
  public static defaultProps = {
    foo: true
  };
  public render() {
    return (
      <p>
        {this.props.children &&
          React.Children.map(this.props.children, x =>
            React.cloneElement(
              x as React.ReactElement,
              { foo: this.props.foo },
              null
            )
          )}
      </p>
    );
  }
}
export class SuperParent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Parent>
        <Child />
        <ChildTwo />
      </Parent>
    );
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SuperParent />
    </div>
  );
}

interface ChildProps {
  foo?: boolean;
}

export class Child extends React.Component<ChildProps> {
  render() {
    const { foo } = this.props;
    return <div>{foo && <p>Hello World!</p>}</div>;
  }
}

export class ChildTwo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return "NO FOO HERE";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you try abstracting the children to a function that checks to see if they're instances of a class, and based off of that inject the props?

for example:

```
protected injectFoo(child){
    if(child instanceof ChildWithProps){
        const propsWithFoo = {
            ...someprops,
            foo: true
        }
      return React.cloneElement(child, propsWithFoo, child.props.children)
    }
    return child
}


public render(){
    <div>
        {React.Children.map(this.props.children, this.injectFoo)}
    </div>
}
```

Comment: As I said in OP, I use this component on a root level. I would need to instanceof hundreds of components.